# sql frequency tables in the aggregate: values as columns

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions, frequency

I have a table like this:

```
id    type    other_fields
1     a      1232
1     b      12
1     a      4324
2     c      4343
2     b      12
2     a      43545
```

I want to aggregate this so that each row would correspond to an id
and have a column for each possible value of type with the corresponding counts in each row:

```
id     tyep_a    type_b    type_c
1      2         1         0
2      1         1         1
```

is there a way to create that in a simple sql query without needing to actually enumerate all possible values explicitly?

Comment: Tag which DBMS(SQL Server, MySQL, PostgreSQL etc ... ) are you using

Comment: In MS SQL-Server you can use `PIVOT` operator

Answer (score 0):

You can use a **`CASE`** with an aggregate function **`SUM`** expression.

**Query**

```
select id,
sum(case type when 'a' then 1 else 0 end) as type_a,
sum(case type when 'b' then 1 else 0 end) as type_b,
sum(case type when 'c' then 1 else 0 end) as type_c
from your_table_name
group by id;
```

This may work irrespective of `RDBMS`. But it is better to you mention the `RDBMS` which you are using. So that, we can make it dynamic.

Comment: This is exactly what I want to avoid. I don't have an a-priori knowledge what are the possible values of type, so I can't write a "case" statement. I try to find a way to this in a generic way, that can be applied to any column.

Comment: @amit Then just mention your **`rdbms`**.